# Plotting vertical cylindrical surfaces

Tags: python, matplotlib

Provided we have a contour on the xy plane, how can we plot "a curtain" raised from the contour to the limiting surface?
An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def figure():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    t1 = np.linspace(0, 8/9, 100)
    x1 = t1
    y1 = (2*t1)**0.5

    f1 = lambda x, y: y
    plt.plot(x1, y1)
    axes.plot_surface(x, y, f1(x, y),color ='red', alpha=0.1)
    axes.set_xlim(-2,2)
    axes.set_ylim(-2,2)

figure()
```

[image]

How to plot a surface from the given line to the limiting surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody wanted help plotting an intersection here [cylinder "cuts" a sphere in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137509/cylinder-cuts-a-sphere-in-python/30137882#30137882) you could use the vertical cylinder part. It uses u, v parameters to generate x, y, z values